# Can I use the two kinds of tense in one sentence?

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

I wrote the sentence as follows.

> “After this experience, I **found** that current methods only **incorporate** one type of information.”

I want to ask that is the sentence’s grammar correct? I use “found” because it happened in the past and I use “incorporate” because it is a phenomena. Can I use the two kinds of tense in one sentence?

Comment: It has unfortunately become common for uneducated native speakers to use "phenomena" as singular.  The singular is "phenomenon" and the plural is "phenomena". I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that all the verbs in a sentence have the same tense.  The verb's tense depends on the meaning of that clause.  It is very common to use tense as you have done in the example.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> “After this experience, I found that current methods only incorporate
> one type of information.”

If you change the tense, you change the meaning. The grammar is still correct.

1. *After this experience, I found that current methods only **incorporate** one type of information.*

This implies that the methods were current then, and are still current now.

2. *After this experience, I found that current methods only **incorporated** one type of information.*

This implies that the methods were current in the past, but may not be current now.